# zipfile is leaving the last few lines off my file - why?

Tags: python, kml, python-2.6, kmz, python-zipfile

So I'm having an issue with using the `zipfile` module in Python. Currently when I try to compress a KML file to create a new KMZ file I'm missing the last few lines. It doesn't seem to matter how long the KML is. I assume this is because zipfile isn't writing the last zipped block.

```
kmz = zipfile.ZipFile(kmzPath , 'w')
kmz.write(kmlPath, 'CORS.kml', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
```

And yes before you ask I have imported **zlib** to do the compression. I've tried to use zlib at the lower level too but have the same issue. I'm stuck.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that you called

```
kmz.close()
```

after the `.write(...)` command, otherwise the full contents of the file won't be flushed to disk. To make sure this happens automatically, always use the `with` context manager, as the file will be closed when the loop is exited:

```
with zipfile.ZipFile(kmzPath, 'w') as kmz:
    kmz.write(kmlPath, 'CORS.kml', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
```

Comment: Hey yeah alright. Thats worked. I usually use **with** as well but got an _AttributeError: ZipFile instance has no attribute '__exit__'_ so thats why it was left out. Since I almost never use *.close() I forgot. Bugger. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess, but according to the `zipfile` documentation:

> You must call [`close()`](https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.close) before exiting your program or essential records will not be written.

You don't indicate that you are in fact calling `kmz.close()` - could that be the problem?